# PHP password_hash() and password_verify() don't match

Tags: php, passwords, password-hash

I'm trying to make a user login system where the password is hashed, I'm using this:

```
function mk_password_hash($password) {
        $options = [
            'cost' => 12,
        ];
        $hashed_password = password_hash($password, PASSWORD_BCRYPT, $options);
        return $hashed_password;
    }
```

Then I store the hashed password in the users table.

When the user tries to login, the script selects the hashed password from the db, then compares it to the password typed by the user:

```
$query = 'SELECT id, status, pass FROM users WHERE email = ? LIMIT 1';
    $stmt = $mysqli->prepare($query);
    $stmt->bind_param('s', $email);
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->store_result();
    $num_rows = $stmt->num_rows;
    if ($num_rows < 1) {
        echo '[error-login-wrong]';
    } else {
        $stmt->bind_result($uid, $user_status, $user_pass);
        $stmt->fetch();
        if ($user_status == 1) {
            if (password_verify($pass, $user_pass)) {
                $_SESSION['my-uid'] = $uid;
                $_SESSION['logged'] = TRUE;
                echo '[success]';
            } else {
                echo '[error-login-wrong]';
            }
        } else {
            echo '[error-login-disabled]';
        }
    }
```

Here $pass is the input from the user, and $user_pass is the hashed password from the db.

Now this always returns false, [error-login-wrong] meaning the password and the hashed password don't match.

NB: there is no time between creating the hashed password and trying to login, so no algorithm change or whatever.

Any explanation?

Comment: There must be a problem with how you're saving the hashed password in the DB.

Comment: What barmar said. Most of the time this problem is due to the field the hash is stored in being too short. Eg: A default bcrypt hash will need 60 bytes for storage.

Comment: the field is varchar(32), maybe I need more?

Comment: you're right! that was the field with varchar(32)! thanks a lot!

Comment: I changed it to varchar(64) and now it's working!